# Servlet forwarding to JSP using RequestDispatcher causing 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

Any idea why forwarding from `servlet` to `JSP` might cause error `500`?

It is this part of the code:

```
session.removeAttribute("cdoChosen");
    String nextJSP = "/EndLandingPage.jsp";
     System.out.println("Redirecting to the final landing page with results.");

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
    dispatcher.forward(request,response);
```

I am using such forwarding in many other `servlets` with no issues. Execution log of the app doesn't say anything, the last line is this:

```
Redirecting to the final landing page with results.
```

Which as you may see in above code, is the result of the `System.out.println`.

I am using `Tomcat v7` and Ubuntu OS from AWS.

I would say the only difference is that I don't have servlet assigned to the JSP. See `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>Visma_UploadInterface</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlets.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/main/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MainPageServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlets.MainPageServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MainPageServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/mainPage/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MappingServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlets.MappingServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MappingServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/mapping/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ListImportServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlets.ListImportServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ListImportServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/listImport/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RejectedRecordsServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlets.RejectedRecordsServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RejectedRecordsServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rejectedRecords/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlets.UploadServlet</servlet-class>

    </servlet>



</web-app>
```

My `doPost()`:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        try{
            String fieldMapping = request.getParameter("fieldMapping");
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            String fileName = (String) session.getAttribute("fileName");
            EloquaListImportToCdo listImportClass = new EloquaListImportToCdo(fieldMapping, session, fileName);
            listImportClass.importList();
            String pathStr = (String) session.getAttribute("filePath");
            Path path = Paths.get(pathStr);
            try {
                Files.delete(path);
            } catch (NoSuchFileException x) {
                System.err.format("%s: no such" + " file or directory%n", path);
            } catch (DirectoryNotEmptyException x) {
                System.err.format("%s not empty%n", path);
            } catch (IOException x) {
                // File permission problems are caught here.
                System.err.println(x);
            }
            session.removeAttribute("cdoChosen");
            String nextJSP = "EndLandingPage.jsp";
            System.out.println("Redirecting to the final landing page with results.");

            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
            dispatcher.forward(request,response);
        }catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }
```

Any idea?

Comment: I can't see any stacktrace... that's what I am saying. I just called doPost of the servlet which then did the processing and then after processing was done it was supposed to redirect. Everything happened, including the sout that it is going to redirect. But the redirect/forward didn't happen.

Comment: `500 Internal Server Error` means there is a exception occurred in the execution. Surround the code in `doPost` and print the stacktrace in the catch block the post it.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam  I have surrounded the whole do post with try catch, I was catching Exception and it is still the same... and I was so sure that this would help with locating the issue. Any idea?

Comment: Post your `doPost` completely.

Comment: There you go. Thanks.

Comment: change `System.out.println(ex.toString());` to `ex.printStackTrace()` also put it in all catch block.

Comment: What do you mean by put it in all catch block? Am I not catching all Exceptions by "Exception ex"? Or do you mean anything else? I am sorry. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You have nested try catch in side the main try those catch blocks.

Comment: Same result. I don't understand that.

Comment: May be the problem is in `EndLandingPage.jsp`. please remove all the content in the JSP and check.

Comment: Same error.... I am sorry for consuming your time... but I am lost.

Comment: Sorry without stacktrace cannot identify the issue

Comment: Yes, I understand, neither do I...

Comment: I found the reason why is that, maybe you could assist me. The reason was that the loading of the page has expired somehow but the Java program was still running in the background. Any idea why is that happening? Session expiration is set to 30 minutes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of it failing was, that the HTTP request has expired after a long time of loading, meaning the PDF file which I was building was not yet created. However, the Java program was still running on server.

Only thing I had to do was adding this to `httpd.conf` of the tomcat:

```
Timeout 600
ProxyTimeout 600
```

If you have the same issue don't forget to reboot the whole server, not just Java server.

Answer (score 0):

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = 
        request.getRequestDispatcher("EndLandingPage.jsp");
```

If you use relative path, you must use `HttpServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher()`. `ServletContext.getRequestDispatcher()` doesn't allow it.

Comment: at which path your EndLandingPage.jsp is located?